# Inserting Items to BoxLayout at Runtime?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout, griffon

I am trying to figure out how I can insert items to BoxLayout at runtime... or achieve a similar effect using a different widget/panel/layout.

The design for the application window is to have several panels stacked vertically (BoxLayout.Y_AXIS).  The user can then insert or delete panels, as well as interact with any widgets that are inside the panel.  My hope would be to bind this to an observable list, where classes representing each panel type are inserted and the UI is updated accordingly.

Thank you for any pointers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[javax.swing.SwingUtilities](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) will allow you to perform operation in the `event dispatcher thread (EDT)` - all operations that update UI must be performed in `EDT`. Also don't hesitate to call, `revalidate()` and `repaint()` methods after you added your components on the container you're adding components to, that will allow parent component to recalculate positions of all elements (including new ones), and redraw itself.

Comment: In order to do this I would need to set up my own Observer/Listener on the panel and rebuild the panel each time it sees a change in the list representing the panel order, then revalidate/repaint.  Correct?  It seems costly (or I know I wouldn't design it optimally).  I had my fingers crossed for a nice bindable element to do the magic for me. =)